# mysql array: if statement in the foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, foreach

I display a mysql query in an html table and I wish to put an IF STATEMENT in the foreach loop to check the length of the column of the lastnames. My goal is to check whether the variable "last_name" is too long (for example 5 characters) and if so to change it with the string "NA". How can I achieve my goal? Is it possible? I've tried with the if statement in the foreach loop but it changes both the column of the "last_name" and the one of the "email".

Here is my PHP CODE:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT tb1.email, tb2.last_name
FROM user AS tb1
INNER JOIN data AS tb2
ON tb1.id = tb2.id";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $cell)  
    if(strlen($cell)>5){
    echo "<td>NA</td>"; 
    }else{
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";  
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/strlen http://php.net/if

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I suggest that you show us your attempt at the `if` statement and let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: I know strlen. The problem is that I want to check only one column and not the entire array. If I check stlren($cell) i get the result for the column "email" and the column "last_name" and not only last_name

Comment: showdev I've edited my code above with the if statement in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking the string length conditionally, based on the current column name.

Since you are using [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), each `$row` will be an associative array with keys (column names) and values.

In the code below, if the column name is "last_name" *and* the value is greater than 5 characters, display "n/a". Otherwise, display the value itself.

```php
foreach ($row as $col => $val)  {
    $val = $col == 'last_name' && strlen($val) > 5 ? 'n/a' : $val;
    echo "<td>$val</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strlen()` function in php to count the number of characters. Use the code below

```
$sql = 
"SELECT tb1.email, tb2.last_name
FROM user AS tb1
INNER JOIN data AS tb2
ON tb1.id = tb2.id";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);

echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$last_name=$row['last_name'];
if(strlen($last_name)>5){
$last_name="NA";
}

echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell)      
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";      
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your help but this code doesn't display what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside you loop:

```
if (strlen($your_last_name_var) > 5)
{
    echo 'ok';
}
```